# Auto Adjustment of UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uiimageview, uistackview

I am currently working on `UIImageView` and I have an API which returns a number of images, maximum =5 and minimum=1, I have to adjust the position of the image based on the response.

Suppose I have five images

1. Restaurant
2. Parking
3. Outdoor pool
4. Interent
5. Bars

API can return 1 or 2 or 5, it varies.

I need to adjust the images accordingly like if 3 images than I have to show three and hide remaining two.

I have tried `UIStackView` but it didn't work as per my requirement and now I am working with `Leading` and `Trailing` constraints but it seems they don't work too.

I there any other workaround to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using UICollectionView as number of images used here are dynamic is number.

Comment: I had add `UICollectionView` but i am unable to add `UICollectionViewCell` in my xib file, am I missing something? 

I have used CollectionView before but in ViewController, it is first time I am using it in xib and it is not allowing me to add cell in collectionview in xib.

Comment: Create object/ reference of cell xib that you have created and use that in cellForRowAtIndex delegate. Is this the way you are doing ?

Comment: If you have got the answer let me know or provide further details so that this question can be closed.

Comment: I am not following you, I have xib in which I have to create `UICollectionView` but xib doesn't allow to add `UICollectionViewCell`. I am stuck between this and sorry I am new to `Objective-C`

Comment: For this you will need a full tutorial. Check this link as it has the required material for you. If still issue remains please post a new question with exact issue that comes

http://www.sledgedev.com/build-a-custom-uicollectionviewcell/